# Why is the background of the editor white but gray in paint?

Tags: python, pyside2

[image]

I don't know why paint and createEditor look different.
It is subtly different in size as well as in color.
I want the two to show the same size and color.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class TestDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(wid)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        wid.setAutoFillBackground(True)

        painter.save()
        painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft())
        wid.resize(option.rect.size())
        wid.render(painter, QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
        painter.restore()
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(wid)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        wid.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        return wid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4,4)
    table.setItemDelegate(TestDelegate())
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: probably something to do with focus? maybe a bigger padding/margin for the QTextFields and highlighted coloring if selected? (not much into Qt anymore)

Comment: Your opinion helped me find the information! Thank you. @Patrick Artner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Share the solution I found.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui


class TestDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TestDelegate, self).__init__(parent)

    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(wid)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        wid.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        painter.save()
        painter.translate(option.rect.topLeft())
        wid.resize(option.rect.size())
        wid.setBackgroundRole(QtGui.QPalette.ColorRole.Base) # <<<<<<<<<<<
        wid.render(painter, QtCore.QPoint(0, 0))
        painter.restore()
    
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        wid = QtWidgets.QWidget(parent=parent)
        layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(wid)
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        layout.addWidget(btn)
        wid.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        wid.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        return wid

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4,4)
    table.setItemDelegate(TestDelegate())
    table.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution. You can self-accept it after I think 48 hours or so.